# Remove hyperlink from Breadcrumb

Tags: asp.net, client-side, breadcrumbs

I have a breadcrumb as :

Level 1 --> Level 2

I want to remove the hyperlink of first link(Level 1) but the text should remain. This is a user control, so I cannot hard code it in control.

Is there anyway I can remove the hyperlink only for first level and only in a particular page ?

Any pointers ??

Comment: The usercontrol is actually a CMS control. So I just used following line in my code.

     <cms:cmsbreadcrumbs id="brumb" runat="server" showcurrentitem="true" selectonlypublished="False" startingpath= "/{0}/{1}/{2}" ignoreshowinnavigation="true" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through child controls inside your control (through `ctl.Controles` collection), investigate each one in your code, and according to your logic, cancel the hyperlink. One of the ways could be hiding or deleting the original hyperlink, and injecting an `asp:literal` instead.